# Set of integers bounded above

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Could you please check the validity of my solution to the following question?

> **Example:** Show that if a set $A$ of integers is bounded above, then $A$ has a largest element.

*My attempt is as follows:* If $A$ is bounded above it has a supremum, say $M$. I will show that $M$ has to be contained by $A$.

Assume it is not so, namely $M \notin A$.

There has to be a number $m\in A$ such that $M-1<m<M$, otherwise $M-1$ would be an upper bound of $A$.

Additionally, there has to be another number $n\in A$ such that $m<n<M$, otherwise $m$ would be an upper bound of $A$.

Now, we can infer the following result,

$-n>-M $ and $M-1<m$ $\Rightarrow$ $0<n-m<1$.

Because $n$ and $m$ are integers, $n-m$ must be an integer. Therefore, the assumption in advance leads to a contradiction and $M$ must be contained by $A$.

Comment: I think you can stop at $M-1<m<M$. How could you find an integer between $M-1$ and $M$?

Comment: It has to be because otherwise $M-1$ will be an upper bound. Is not it right?

Comment: Yes, and that's your contradiction right there

Comment: I still do not understand.

Comment: We assumed $M$ is the least upper bound. So $M-1$ is not an upper bound. So there must be some $m \in A$ with $m>A$, But as you've said, $M-1<m<M$. But $m \in A$ implies $m$ is an integer. But there is no integer between $M-1$ and $M$

Comment: The original proof was good.  No reason to change it, $M$  "could" be $88.88$.

Comment: Zach, how can you compare a number with a set?

Comment: I meant $m>M-1$. That was a typo.